# Generic exception when developing Spring Boot 3 API with Insomnia

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

```
    package com.example.hotel.repo.implementation;  
    import com.example.hotel.domain.Role;
    import com.example.hotel.domain.User;
    import com.example.hotel.exception.ApiException;
    import com.example.hotel.repo.RoleRepository;
    import com.example.hotel.repo.UserRepository;
    import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
    import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    import org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException;
    import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource;
    import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate;
    import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.SqlParameterSource;
    import org.springframework.jdbc.support.GeneratedKeyHolder;
    import org.springframework.jdbc.support.KeyHolder;
    import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
    
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder;
    
    import java.util.Collection;
    import java.util.Objects;
    import java.util.UUID;
    
    import static com.example.hotel.enumeration.RoleType.ROLE_USER;
    import static com.example.hotel.enumeration.VerificationType.ACCOUNT;
    import static com.example.hotel.query.UserQuery.*;
    import static java.util.Map.of;
    import static java.util.Objects.requireNonNull;
    
    @Repository
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    @Slf4j
    public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository <User> {
        private final NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbc;
        private final RoleRepository <Role> roleRepository;
        private final BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder;
    
        @Override
        public User create(User user) {
            //check the email whether unique
            if (getEmailCount(user.getEmail().trim().toLowerCase()) > 0)
                throw new ApiException("Email already in use. Please use another email and try again");
            //save new user
           try {
                KeyHolder holder = new GeneratedKeyHolder(); //get the id from the database
    
                SqlParameterSource parameters = getSqlParameterSource(user); // set the parameters and get the firstname lastname and details
                jdbc.update(INSERT_USER_QUERY, parameters, holder); // to update the database after getting the user details
                //setting a id
                user.setId(requireNonNull(holder.getKey()).longValue());
                //setting a role
                roleRepository.addRoleToUser(user.getId(), ROLE_USER.name());
                // send verification url
                String verificationUrl = getVerificationUrl(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), ACCOUNT.getType());
                // save url in verification table
                jdbc.update(INSERT_ACCOUNT_VERIFICATION_URL_QUERY, of("userId", user.getId(), "url", verificationUrl)); //userId and url is mapped to INSERT_ACCOUNT_VERIFICATION_URL_QUERY
                // send email to user with verification url
                // emailService.sendVerificationUrl(user.getFirstName(), user.getEmail(), verificationUrl, ACCOUNT);
                user.setEnabled(false);
                user.setNotLocked(true);
                // return newly created user
                return user;
                // if any errors, throw exception with proper message
            } catch (Exception exception) {
               log.error("Error occurred while creating a user: {}", exception.getMessage(), exception);
               throw new ApiException("An error occurred. Please try again.");
           }
        }
        @Override
        public Collection<User> list(int page, int pageSize) {
            return null;
        }
    
        @Override
        public User get(Long id) {
            return null;
        }
    
        @Override
        public User update(User data) {
            return null;
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean delete(Long id) {
            return false;
        }
        private Integer getEmailCount(String email) {
            return jdbc.queryForObject(COUNT_USER_EMAIL_QUERY, of("email", email), Integer.class);
        }
    
        private SqlParameterSource getSqlParameterSource(User user) {
            return new MapSqlParameterSource()
                    .addValue("firstName", user.getFirstName())
                    .addValue("lastName", user.getLastName())
                    .addValue("email", user.getEmail())
                    .addValue("password", encoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
    
        }
        private String getVerificationUrl(String key, String type){
            return ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath().path("/user/verify/" + type + "/" + key).toUriString(); //backend url is extracted
        }
    
    
    
    }
    
    package com.example.hotel.repo;
    
    import com.example.hotel.domain.User;
    
    import java.util.Collection;
    
    public interface UserRepository <T extends User>{
        /* Basic CRUD Operation */
        T create(T data);
        Collection <T> list(int page, int pageSize);
        T get(Long id);
    
        T update(T data);
        boolean delete(Long id);
    
        /* More CRUD Operation */
    
    }
    
    package com.example.hotel.domain;
    
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
    import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
    import lombok.Data;
    import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
    import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;
    
    import static com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT;
    
    @Data
    @SuperBuilder
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @JsonInclude(NON_DEFAULT)
    public class Role {
        private Long id;
        private String name;
        private String permission;
    
    }
    package com.example.hotel.domain;
    
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
    import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
    import jakarta.validation.constraints.Email;
    import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
    import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
    import lombok.Data;
    import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
    import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;
    
    import java.time.LocalDateTime;
    
    import static com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT;
    
    @Data
    @SuperBuilder
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @JsonInclude(NON_DEFAULT)
    public class User {
        private Long id;
        @NotEmpty(message = "First name cannot be empty")
        private String firstName;
        @NotEmpty(message = "Last name cannot be empty")
        private String lastName;
        @NotEmpty(message = "Email cannot be empty")
        @Email(message = "Invalid email. Please enter a valid email")
        private String email;
        @NotEmpty(message = "Password cannot be empty")
        private String password;
        private String address;
        private String phone;
        private String title;
        private String bio;
        private String imageUrl;
        private boolean enabled;
        private boolean isNotLocked;
        private boolean isUsingMfa;
        private LocalDateTime createdAt;
    }
```

**These are my class files, As i have been trying to insert data into the database via Insomnia I have been as**

```
    {
    
        "firstName": "ijas",
        "lastName": "me",
        "email": "undyin2@gmail.com",
        "password" : "123456"
    }
```

I get the response as

```
    {
        "timestamp": "2023-09-21T14:17:06.086+00:00",
        "status": 500,
        "error": "Internal Server Error",
        "path": "/user/register"
    }
```

The stack trace gives

```
    "C:\Program Files\jdk-20_windows-x64_bin\jdk-20.0.1\bin\java.exe" -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true "-Dmanagement.endpoints.jmx.exposure.include=*" "-javaagent:D:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=59724:D:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\Hotel-Management\server\target\classes;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\3.1.3\spring-boot-starter-web-3.1.3.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\3.1.3\spring-boot-starter-3.1.3.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\3.1.3\spring-boot-3.1.3.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\3.1.3\spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.3.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\3.1.3\spring-boot-starter-logging-3.1.3.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.4.11\logback-classic-1.4.11.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.4.11\logback-core-1.4.11.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.20.0\log4j-to-slf4j-2.20.0.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.20.0\log4j-api-2.20.0.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\2.0.7\jul-to-slf4j-2.0.7.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\2.1.1\jakarta.annotation-api-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.33\snakeyaml-1.33.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\3.1.3\spring-boot-starter-json-3.1.3.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.15.2\jackson-databind-2.15.2.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.15.2\jackson-annotations-2.15.2.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.15.2\jackson-core-2.15.2.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.15.2\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.15.2.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.15.2\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.15.2.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.15.2\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.15.2.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\3.1.3\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-3.1.3.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\10.1.12\tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\10.1.12\tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.12.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\6.0.11\spring-web-6.0.11.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\6.0.11\spring-beans-6.0.11.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\io\micrometer\micrometer-observation\1.11.3\micrometer-observation-1.11.3.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\io\micrometer\micrometer-commons\1.11.3\micrometer-commons-1.11.3.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\6.0.11\spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\6.0.11\spring-context-6.0.11.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\6.0.11\spring-expression-6.0.11.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-security\3.1.3\spring-boot-starter-security-3.1.3.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\6.0.11\spring-aop-6.0.11.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-config\6.1.3\spring-security-config-6.1.3.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-core\6.1.3\spring-security-core-6.1.3.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-crypto\6.1.3\spring-security-crypto-6.1.3.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-web\6.1.3\spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-validation\3.1.3\spring-boot-starter-validation-3.1.3.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\10.1.12\tomcat-embed-el-10.1.12.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\validator\hibernate-validator\8.0.1.Final\hibernate-validator-8.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\jakarta\validation\jakarta.validation-api\3.0.2\jakarta.validation-api-3.0.2.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.5.3.Final\jboss-logging-3.5.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.5.1\classmate-1.5.1.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\3.1.3\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-3.1.3.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\3.1.3\spring-boot-starter-aop-3.1.3.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.20\aspectjweaver-1.9.20.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\3.1.3\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-3.1.3.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\5.0.1\HikariCP-5.0.1.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\6.0.11\spring-jdbc-6.0.11.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\orm\hibernate-core\6.2.7.Final\hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\jakarta\persistence\jakarta.persistence-api\3.1.0\jakarta.persistence-api-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\jakarta\transaction\jakarta.transaction-api\2.0.1\jakarta.transaction-api-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\6.0.6.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-6.0.6.Final.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\io\smallrye\jandex\3.0.5\jandex-3.0.5.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.14.6\byte-buddy-1.14.6.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\4.0.3\jaxb-runtime-4.0.3.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-core\4.0.3\jaxb-core-4.0.3.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\angus\angus-activation\2.0.1\angus-activation-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\4.0.3\txw2-4.0.3.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\4.1.2\istack-commons-runtime-4.1.2.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\jakarta\inject\jakarta.inject-api\2.0.1\jakarta.inject-api-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\antlr\antlr4-runtime\4.10.1\antlr4-runtime-4.10.1.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\3.1.3\spring-data-jpa-3.1.3.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\3.1.3\spring-data-commons-3.1.3.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\6.0.11\spring-orm-6.0.11.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\6.0.11\spring-tx-6.0.11.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\2.0.7\slf4j-api-2.0.7.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\6.0.11\spring-aspects-6.0.11.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\com\mysql\mysql-connector-j\8.0.33\mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\bind\jakarta.xml.bind-api\4.0.0\jakarta.xml.bind-api-4.0.0.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\jakarta\activation\jakarta.activation-api\2.1.2\jakarta.activation-api-2.1.2.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\6.0.11\spring-core-6.0.11.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\6.0.11\spring-jcl-6.0.11.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.18.28\lombok-1.18.28.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\org\modelmapper\modelmapper\3.1.1\modelmapper-3.1.1.jar com.example.hotel.HotelBackend
    
      .   ____          _            __ _ _
     /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
    ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
     \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
      '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
     =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
     :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.3)
    
    2023-09-21T19:59:18.917+05:30  INFO 1636 --- [           main] com.example.hotel.HotelBackend           : Starting HotelBackend using Java 20.0.1 with PID 1636 (C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\Hotel-Management\server\target\classes started by ASUS in C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\Hotel-Management\server)
    2023-09-21T19:59:18.919+05:30  INFO 1636 --- [           main] com.example.hotel.HotelBackend           : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
    2023-09-21T19:59:19.287+05:30  INFO 1636 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
    2023-09-21T19:59:19.329+05:30  INFO 1636 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 37 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
    2023-09-21T19:59:19.631+05:30  INFO 1636 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
    2023-09-21T19:59:19.637+05:30  INFO 1636 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
    2023-09-21T19:59:19.637+05:30  INFO 1636 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.12]
    2023-09-21T19:59:19.691+05:30  INFO 1636 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
    2023-09-21T19:59:19.691+05:30  INFO 1636 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 746 ms
    2023-09-21T19:59:19.775+05:30  INFO 1636 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
    2023-09-21T19:59:19.807+05:30  INFO 1636 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.2.7.Final
    2023-09-21T19:59:19.808+05:30  INFO 1636 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000406: Using bytecode reflection optimizer
    2023-09-21T19:59:19.896+05:30  INFO 1636 --- [           main] o.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator        : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
    2023-09-21T19:59:19.977+05:30  INFO 1636 --- [           main] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
    2023-09-21T19:59:19.987+05:30  INFO 1636 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
    2023-09-21T19:59:20.193+05:30  INFO 1636 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@6e5f5478
    2023-09-21T19:59:20.194+05:30  INFO 1636 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
    2023-09-21T19:59:20.341+05:30  INFO 1636 --- [           main] o.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator        : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
    2023-09-21T19:59:20.755+05:30  INFO 1636 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
    2023-09-21T19:59:20.787+05:30  INFO 1636 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
    2023-09-21T19:59:20.941+05:30  INFO 1636 --- [           main] o.s.d.j.r.query.QueryEnhancerFactory     : Hibernate is in classpath; If applicable, HQL parser will be used.
    2023-09-21T19:59:21.027+05:30  WARN 1636 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
    2023-09-21T19:59:21.219+05:30  INFO 1636 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
    2023-09-21T19:59:21.224+05:30  INFO 1636 --- [           main] com.example.hotel.HotelBackend           : Started HotelBackend in 2.539 seconds (process running for 2.927)
```

**So i have been trying to solve this error for long time, i would really appreciate if somebody could help me solve this error.**

I will also share the query codes below as to how it is queried into the database. And to note, i get data inserted successfully to the database yet i get an error of exception that leads me to a generic stack trace as shared.

```
    package com.example.hotel.query;
    
    public class RoleQuery {
        public static final String INSERT_ROLE_TO_USER_QUERY = "INSERT INTO UserRoles (user_id, role_id) VALUES (:userId, :roleId) ";
        public static final String SELECT_ROLE_BY_NAME_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM Roles WHERE name = :name";
    }
    
    package com.example.hotel.query;
    
    public class UserQuery {
    
        public static final String INSERT_USER_QUERY = "INSERT INTO Users (first_name, last_name, email, password) VALUES (:firstName, :lastName, :email, :password)";
        //NamedParmeter is used this way.
        public static final String COUNT_USER_EMAIL_QUERY = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE email = :email";
        public static final String INSERT_ACCOUNT_VERIFICATION_URL_QUERY = "INSERT INTO AccountVerifications (user_id, url) VALUES (:userId, :url)";
    }
    [![enter image description here][1]][1]
  
    
    
      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Zo00.png
```

Comment: what does this question have to do with spring security? also the logs contain no stack trace or no error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.